# Getting all <TR> tags in an array and referring it

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, html-parsing

I am trying to get all `<TR>` tags within `<TABLE>` tag in an array and I am trying to refer it like ***arrayname[1], arrayname[2]*** . Then I am looking forward to set a unique ***title*** attribute to `<TR>` tag's, using `idArr[1].setAttribute("title", "myClass");`

Here is the code I have written, which does not works. Can anyone guide me what's wrong in it !!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
var idArr = [];
var formm=document.getElementById("form1");
var trs = formm.getElementsByTagName("tr");
alert(trs.length);
for(var i=0;i<trs.length;i++)
{
   idArr.push(trs[i].id);
   alert(idArr.innerText);
}
idArr[1].setAttribute("title", "myClass");
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>One</td>
<td>Two</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>EFG</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you let us know what your end-game is? Are you looking to change the values, just reference the contents? A little more to the question will help us give you a little more help. Right off the back a jQuery .each would be a better way to go..

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `idArr` is an array, not connected in any way to the DOM; it has no `innerText` property, which you're trying to display in your loop, nor do the strings you're putting into it have `setAttribute` methods assigned to them. Your `<tr>` elements don't have `id` values, so `idArr.push(trs[i].id)` is going to push `""` into the array.

Comment: There is no sense in in the code... you are pushing into the array an attribute that is not there and then expect an innerText from it.

Comment: Why the downvote guys? He has at least provided what he has. the fact it is wrong is why he is asking!

Comment: @Darren: From the tooltip on the downvote button: *"This question shows no research effort; it is unclear or not useful."* The slightest effort (say, walking through with the debuggers that exist on all browsers, or even glancing at the odd text on how to write JavaScript or about the DOM) would deal with most of these issues. But yes, perhaps the DV is a tad harsh.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - 'no research effort'... really? I see a lot of code there, also see that he has at least tried. This in itself shows an amount of research effort. I think some people just forget they started somewhere with little to no knowledge once upon a time.

Comment: @Darren: I help out newbies all the time. But again, agreed the downvotes seem a bit harsh.

Comment: Hello Darren, I am writing this code for OBIEE to achieve an output which is not an inbuilt feature in it. Hence I need to refer to each of the TR elements dynamically in javascript and set a title attribute. i could not get any help in OBIEE forum hence thought asking here....Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @Darren: Nah, people don't forget. Instead they remember all the work and research they did on their own before asking someone else to help.

Comment: @user1689607 - I'm not going to continue a debate here - this Q is already a little hijacked. Not sure how you know what or how much research the OP has done.

Comment: @Darren: I didn't say that I do know. I just said that people remember all the work and research they did on their own as beginners. I don't see evidence of that here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple considerations:

- The elements do not exist when the code runs,
- You don't need the Array for what you're doing.

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>EFG</td>
        </tr>

        </table>
    </form>

 <!-- Now your script will not run until the elements above are loaded-->
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    var formm=document.getElementById("form1");
    var trs = formm.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(var i = 0, len = trs.length; i < len; i++) {
        trs[i].setAttribute("title", "myClass");
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I got rid of the extra Array code, and I moved the script to the bottom of the page so that it doesn't run until the DOM above it has loaded.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to refer to each of the TR elements dynamically in javascript and set a title attribute.

Your code getting the `tr` elements and looping through them is fine, although you need to move it (more below). There's no need for the array at all, and that's where you're getting into trouble.

You haven't said *what* you need to put in the title, but just do that directly:

```
for(var i=0;i<trs.length;i++)
{
   trs[i].title = "The title goes here";
}
```

or

```
for(var i=0;i<trs.length;i++)
{
   trs[i].setAttribute("title", "The title goes here");
}
```

(`title` is a *reflected property* on `HTMLElement` instances, which is why there are two ways to do that).

Also note that as [userSomeNumberHere points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252963/157247), your code runs before the elements below it exist. You need to move your code to underneath the elements it operates on.

Comment: I believe the second way is incorrect. Shouldn't it be `trs[i].setAttribute("title", "The title goes here");`?

Answer (score 0):

Like in the comments under your post you have an critical error in your code. Look at the comments (//...)

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var idArr = []; //should rename to elemArr or somethink like this
var formm=document.getElementById("form1");
var trs = formm.getElementsByTagName("tr");
alert(trs.length);
for(var i=0;i<trs.length;i++)
{
   idArr.push(trs[i]); //here you push only the id and not the element
   alert(idArr.innerText);
}
idArr[1].setAttribute("title", "myClass");
</script>
```

but i don't know why you go through the trs array and convert it to an other array. you can simpely use this: `trs[1].setAttribute("title", "myClass");`

greetings!